# Error configuring IIS Express when creating new Web Service project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, iis-express, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a new Web Service application, but as Visual Studio is setting up the solution, it gives me an error:

> Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:
>
> Filename:
>   \?\C:\Users...\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
>
> Error: Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has
>   changed on disk

I'm not using IIS Express (and don't want to). Is there a VS setting that I can change?

Note that this is happening in VS 2012 & 2013.